# Four Wildcards in a Like String Comparison

Tags: sql-server

Trying to get my head around using four wildcard characters in a `like` string comparison.

```
select 1 where '%'+field1+'%' not like '%'+field2+'%'
```

Is this pointless? Working left to right, field1 must not exist anywhere in '%'+field2+'%', but since a wildcard can be anything doesn't that mean it will always exist? Are any of the wildcard characters in the statement irrelevant?

In my case I'm trying to find where `field1` (a free text field) doesn't exist in the value from `field2` (a defined list).

**Currently Using**

```
select field1, field2, COUNT(1) as 'Count' from filteredNew_address 
where field1 like '%Place%' and field1 LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
and REPLACE(field1, ' ', '') not like REPLACE(field2, ' ', '')
group by field1, field2
order by 'count' desc
```

I get the following results;

```
field1          field2
Place 6         Place
Place 12        Place 24
Place 4         Place 7
Place 6b        Place 6
Place 1         Place 7
Place 2         Outside Country
...
```

Out of the returned values there, the only one that is an issue is the Place 6b record. This should match to the field2 record and so should not be returned.

To correct this I tried changing to;

```
and REPLACE(field1, ' ', '') not like REPLACE(field2, ' ', '')
```

But this removed the first result (Place 6, Place) which should be returned.

Comment: Can you please give an example or two of the data in each field? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: NP, see my currently using section.

Comment: I see the example row (thanks), but it seems overly simplistic. It doesn't show a list of items, just a single item, yet you say that field2 is a "defined list". Can you give a few examples to show various situations that would AND would _not_ match?

Comment: My apologies, I've expanded a bit more to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: No prob. It does seem clearer now but not 100%. Why did you want wildcards for "field1"? What happens if field1 = "Place 22" and field2 = "Place 222"? That is the opposite direction of subset from the Place 6b/Place 6 example but is implied by wanting wildcards also on field1.

Comment: Basically I want to see where the fields don't match. But to elaborate since F1 is entered by users it can be incorrect. F2 contents will generally be Place, Place1, Place2 etc. If a user has entered Place 2West I don't want this returned if F2 is Place2. Count doesn't need to be precise, I'm just trying to find the scale of a problem of addresses being incorrect.

Comment: If it is a case where F1 is Place 2 and F2 is Place 22, ideally this would be returned but I would settle for them not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

adding wildcards to field1 is pointless. When you are using whilcards is the same as saying search for pattern x in column y. Adding whildcards to the column being searched doesn't change anything.